# Python - How can I speed up the code to create random lists and stop when palindrome found?

Tags: python, list, random

so I was basically messing around with some exercises (started coding 4 months ago) and I came with an interesting exercise which I wanted to exploit a little bit more. What I want the program to do is quite simple:

Create random lists and check for it to be a palindrome, if it is, break and print the list, time taken and tries needed. I could clean the code up to this but I want to know if there is any cleaner or faster way to perform. I tried with a function but I couldn't make it work faster so I discarded it.

I've added a timer so after 10 seconds, it will stop and tell me the tries, for this I used:

- A list of 2 values,
- From 1
- Up to 999,999,999

so it will never find it in under 10 seconds.
3,150,000 tries was my best.

Thank you in advance! Hope you guys can teach me some more!

````
import random
is_same = False

from timeit import default_timer
import random
is_same = False

print("\n**Check how many tries it requires to find a palindrome list**\n")
r2 = int(input("How long would you like the list to be? "))
a1 = int(input("From what number?: "))
a2 = int(input("Up to?: "))
t1_start = default_timer()
limit1 = 10
c = 0

while not is_same:
    while default_timer() < t1_start+10:
        list1 = [random.randint(a1, a2) for x in range(1, r2+1)]
        c += 1
        if list1 == list1[::-1]:
            is_same = True
            print(f"\n'{len(list1)}' Elements in list\n")
            print(list1)
            print(f"¡Palindrome!")
            break
    break

t1_stop = default_timer()
print("\n\nIt took around ", t1_stop-t1_start, "seconds.")

print(F"\nTries that had to be performed were: {c:,}\n")```
````

Comment: `list1[::-1]` makes a full copy of `list1` just for the comparison, which is relatively expensive. It would be much faster to do something like walk `list1` manually and compare the first and last character, then the second and second last character..., and `break` when you find a mismatch.

Comment: oh I actually had a previous code to do that with a variable i = 0 and another o = -1 to compare like this: if (x[i])-(x[o])!=0: break, else: continue i += 1, o -= 1. Would that be faster then?

Comment: Alright I will then try both and let you know! Thanks!!

Comment: Yes. The more Pythonic way to check this would be something like [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/ae78bd6463e7d3bb8ae197864d95f4e5) though. `reversed` doesn't create a reversed copy like `[::-1]` does. Instead, it iterates the sequence in reverse. I'm zipping that with the original list, then checking if all the pairs match. Often, you don't need to do manual indexing of lists. Sometimes you do, but it isn't as frequent as in languages like C where that's your only option.

Comment: Thank you, that's a new resource I've never considered. I will use the function you created. Thanks again!

Comment: I recommend getting familiar with all the functions used in that code. `all` and `zip` especially are incredibly useful functions.

Comment: Sure will do! I didn't hear from all() until today. Thanks again!